# object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Задача:Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры данные в формате: english word:перевод 1, перевод 2. Потом преобразовывает и помещает в словарь, у которого ключом будет английское слова, а значениями- список[перевод1, перевод2,..переводN].

Предположим, после анализа данных вы хотите записать данные в новый файл excel. Как бы так, ручками работает:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Idiom': ['A blessing in disguise', 'A dime a dozen', 'Beat around the bush', 'Better late than never'],
                   'Meaning': ['a good thing that seemed bad at first', 'Something common', 'Avoid saying what you mean','Better to arrive late than not to come at all'],
                   })
```

Но вот коды выдают ошибку в первом:

```
list object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Во втором

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

**Код 1**

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

my_dict = {}
m = int(input("Задайте количество слов в вашем словаре: "))
print("""\nВведите английское слово(фразу) в формате:
слово: перевод1, перевод2, …, перевод N\n""")

while len(my_dict) < m:
    inp = input("слово: ").split(":")
    myData = my_dict[inp[0].strip()] = inp[1].replace(",", " ").split()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
myData.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

**Код 2**

```
import pandas as pd

# import xlsxwriter
input = input('введите так: английское слово: перевод1, перевод2, перевод3: ')
myData = dict([[input.split(':')[0], input.split(':')[1:]]])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
myData.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

код рабочий, еще осталось транслятор привентить:
**Код 3**

```
    import pandas as pd
    lst = [] # Создаем пустой список
    while True: # Цикл
        npt = [i for i in input('Введите данные: ').split()] #Через пробел вводим данные, выход из цикла - пустая строка
        if npt == []:
            break
        else: #Записываем в наш список данные, english, translation
            lst.append({
                'English': npt[0:3],
                'Translation': [ i for i in npt[-3:]] # вводим 6 имен животных
                })
            print(type(lst))
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lst)
            #df = pd.DataFrame(lst).transpose()
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Python_Translator.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
            workbook = writer.book
            worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
            format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
            format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
            worksheet.set_column('B:B', 80, format1)
            worksheet.set_column('C:C', 35, format1)
            worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
            writer.save()
```

Comment: `myData = my_dict[inp[0].strip()] = inp[1].replace(",", " ").split()` зачем вы так делаете? :) `split` возвращает список, а при таком присваивании, в `myData` список окажется. Для второго случая вы явно в `myData = ` поместили объект словаря. А у списка и словаря нет методов `to_excel`. По-моему, это метод из pandas, поэтому нужно те объекты привести в объект pandas (`pd.DataFrame`), тогда у вас вопрос должен быть о том как список/словарь положить в `pd.DataFrame` :)

Comment: Конкректно заданный вопрос решает половину дела. " как список/словарь положить в pd.DataFrame"

Answer (score 3):

Что касается преобразования словаря в DataFrame :

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
print(type(data))
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(res)
print(type(res))
```

Вывод :

```
    <class 'dict'>
       col_1 col_2
    0      3     a
    1      2     b
    2      1     c
    3      0     d
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Что касается преобразования списка в DataFrame :

```
     lst = [['Jon','Mark','Maria','Jill','Jack'],['Smith','Brown','Lee','Jones','Ford'],[21,38,42,28,55]]
        print(type(lst))
        df = pd.DataFrame(lst).transpose()
        df.columns = ['First_Name','Last_Name','Age']
        print(df)
        print(type(df))
```

Вывод :

```
<class 'list'>
  First_Name Last_Name Age
0        Jon     Smith  21
1       Mark     Brown  38
2      Maria       Lee  42
3       Jill     Jones  28
4       Jack      Ford  55
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

[Документация](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Метод transpose() гениальный. Спасибо за наводку

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо путем преобразования словаря в DataFrame . Теперь добавлю транслятор google в python. Постараюсь

Comment: Если Вам помог ответ, можете поставить "галочку" о его принятии.

Comment: Еще хотелось бы транслятор привинтить. Подумаю, может вопросы возникнут. Так то по частям, все есть, осталось только транслятор привентить элегантно, не по быдокодерски. И еще репу + вам поставить. Только не знаю, как плюсы в репу ставить